# DB2 connection string failing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, odbc, connection-string

I am connecting to a DB2 DB with an ODBC Connection. This Connection string works perfectly when I run the page locally through VS 2017.  When I publish the page and try to access the data through postman or a URL, I get the following error

ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

I was under the assumption that the ODBC driver would take care of this.  Here is my very simple connection string.

connectionString = @"DSN=XXX;UID=XXX;Pwd=XXX;";

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use Windows Control Panel : Administrative Tools : ODBC Data Source.

Comment: This was fixed.  I found the proper connection string.  TY